# Is there a fruiting plant that can grow in an office environment?

Tags: indoors, plant-recommendations, light, office-gardening

In the office there is an abundance of fluorescent light and that's about it. The temperature stays around 70 ºF (21 ºC)  I think.

Could I grow a fruiting plant in these conditions? I may be able to add a lamp with a full spectrum light bulb to help the plant out.  It can't be anything fancy though.

I was hoping I could grow a small hot pepper plant, but I don't mind if I have to settle for something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can probably get a number of fruiting plants to flower and set fruit once indoors.  I have seen coffee plants, citrus and members of the fig family flower and set fruit or seed indoors under fluorescents.

The problem is that flowering and fruiting takes a lot of energy.  If the plant does not have more illumination than standard indoor light levels allow this comes from energy stored in the roots.  The usual issues with growing indoors also apply, low humidity, lack of pollinators.

I believe you would be most successful with a citrus plant like a [Calamondin orange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calamondin).  If you can grow it in a high light area next to a window during the flowering then you could sustain in under fluorescents during the fruit cycle.

Comment: I don't have access to any windows :I but growing that orange tree would be awesome if I could with just artifical light.

Answer (score 6):

Peppers and some tomatoes will easily fruit indoors, provided they get enough light. You might want to try indoor avocados too, and keep the size small by pruning.

Comment: you think if they had the office lights plus a small lamp with a full spectrum blub directly above will be enough? I wished I had windows :(